# Chart.js - How to update chart data with interval

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a doughnut chart that gets data from an API. The chart displays ok but I can't get the chart data to update, and do that every 2 seconds. I have tried and searched many topics but most are outdated versions of chart.js and my javascript skills are poor.

**Chart.js v3.9.1**

```
const totalRunTime = current_array.MTConnectStreams.Streams.DeviceStream.ComponentStream[12].Samples.DynamicBasicData[1];
const totalTimeRemaining = current_array.MTConnectStreams.Streams.DeviceStream.ComponentStream[12].Samples.DynamicBasicData[13];
const timeRemaining = ((totalTimeRemaining / totalRunTime) * 100)

// Setup
const datapoints = [(100 - timeRemaining), timeRemaining];
const data = {
  datasets: [{
      data: datapoints,
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(20, 121, 255, 0.7)', 'rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.5)'],
      borderWidth: 1,
      cutout: '70%'
  }]
};

// Counter
const counter = {
  id: 'counter',
  beforeDraw( chart, args, options ) {
    const { ctx, chartArea: { top, right, bottom, left, width, height } } = chart;
    ctx.save();

    ctx.font = options.fontSize + 'px ' + options.fontFamily;
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = options.fontColor;
    ctx.fillText(datapoints[0].toFixed(3) + '%', width / 2, (height / 2) + (options.fontSize * 0.34));
  }
};

// Config
const config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      counter: {
        fontColor: '#193b68',
        fontSize: '16',
        fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro Medium'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [counter]
};

// Render init
const doughnutChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('doughnutChart'),
  config
);

setInterval(function addData(chart, data) {
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
      dataset.data = data;
  });
  chart.update('none');
  }, 2000
);
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="doughnutChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's not appearing to update because you're calling your data and storing in a variable which, from the scope of the application had not changed.

If you move your data request to a function and then call that from the initialising code *and* within `setInterval` you should see your data being updated freshly with each call to the function `getData`.

Here's a version of your code with what I mean, where `getData()` is used instead of `datapoints`:

```
const getData = () => {
  console.log('Requesting data')
  const totalRunTime = current_array.MTConnectStreams.Streams.DeviceStream.ComponentStream[12].Samples.DynamicBasicData[1];
  const totalTimeRemaining = current_array.MTConnectStreams.Streams.DeviceStream.ComponentStream[12].Samples.DynamicBasicData[13];
  const timeRemaining = ((totalTimeRemaining / totalRunTime) * 100)
  return [(100 - timeRemaining), timeRemaining]
}

const data = {
  datasets: [{
      data: getData(),
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(20, 121, 255, 0.7)', 'rgba(208, 208, 208, 0.5)'],
      borderWidth: 1,
      cutout: '70%'
  }]
};

const counter = {
  id: 'counter',
  beforeDraw( chart, args, options ) {
    const { ctx, chartArea: { top, right, bottom, left, width, height } } = chart;
    ctx.save();

    ctx.font = options.fontSize + 'px ' + options.fontFamily;
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = options.fontColor;
    ctx.fillText(getData()[0].toFixed(3) + '%', width / 2, (height / 2) + (options.fontSize * 0.34));
  }
};

const config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      counter: {
        fontColor: '#193b68',
        fontSize: '16',
        fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro Medium'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [counter]
};

const doughnutChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('chart'),
  config
);

setInterval(function addData(chart, data) {
  console.log('updating', Date.now())
  doughnutChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
      dataset.data = getData();
  });
  doughnutChart.update('none');
  }, 2000
);
```

Here's a [codepen of an updating version](https://codepen.io/altescape/pen/ZERYEyp) but with random values used instead of your data requests.

This might be the problem and I hope this helps you.

One tip is to use console.log to see what's being called and placing your code in functions can make it easier to debug too by seeing where and when it is being called by using `console.log` or `debugger`.

Comment: Thank you. This made the whole thing allot more clear.